# Как получить доступ к определенному пикселю *.bmp файла средствани WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, bmp

Возможно ли средствами WinAPI получить масив пикселей(RGB/RGBA) независимо от устройства? Таким образом, чтобы не приходилось вручную парсить файл, получить массив данных(пикселей) согласно разрядности(глубине цвета) изображения.
Желательно чтобы работало независимо от RLA, карт цветов.
Только начинаю разбираться с WinAPI буду благодарен за помощь в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#include <wrl/client.h>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Wincodec.h>

#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

::HRESULT
Verify_Succeeded(const ::HRESULT hr)
{
    if(!SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ::exit(-1);
    }
    return hr;
}

::std::vector<::std::uint8_t>
Extract_Data
(
    const ::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IWICImagingFactory> p_factory
,   const ::LPCWSTR                                      psz_file_path
)
{
    //  Создаем декодер для файла.
    ::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IWICBitmapDecoder> p_decoder{};
    Verify_Succeeded
    (
        p_factory->CreateDecoderFromFilename
        (
            psz_file_path
        ,   nullptr
        ,   GENERIC_READ
        ,   WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand
        ,   &p_decoder
        )
    );
    //  Создаем декодер для кадра (в простом битмапе только один кадр, хотя в
    //  других графических форматах их может присутствовать несколько).
    ::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IWICBitmapFrameDecode> p_frame_decode{};
    Verify_Succeeded(p_decoder->GetFrame(0, &p_frame_decode));
    //  Создаем конвертер, который позаботится, чтобы мы получили данные в
    //  нужном нам формате, независимо от исходного.
    ::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IWICFormatConverter> p_converter{};
    Verify_Succeeded(p_factory->CreateFormatConverter(&p_converter));
    Verify_Succeeded
    (
        p_converter->Initialize
        (
            p_frame_decode.Get()
        ,   GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA
        ,   WICBitmapDitherTypeNone
        ,   nullptr
        ,   0
        ,   WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
        )
    );
    //  Извлекаем массив BGRA пикселей.
    ::UINT width{};
    ::UINT height{};
    Verify_Succeeded(p_converter->GetSize(&width, &height));
    const ::UINT stride_bytes_count{width * 4};
    const ::UINT buffer_bytes_count{stride_bytes_count * height};
    ::std::vector<::std::uint8_t> buffer{};
    buffer.resize(buffer_bytes_count);
    Verify_Succeeded
    (
        p_converter->CopyPixels
        (
            nullptr, stride_bytes_count, buffer_bytes_count, buffer.data()
        )
    );
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    Verify_Succeeded
    (
        ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)
    );
    {
        ::Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<::IWICImagingFactory> p_factory{};
        Verify_Succeeded
        (
            ::CoCreateInstance
            (
                CLSID_WICImagingFactory
            ,   nullptr
            ,   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER
            ,   IID_IWICImagingFactory
            ,   &p_factory
            )
        );
        auto const raw_pixels{Extract_Data(p_factory, L"test.bmp")};
        //  делаем что-нибудь
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю классический вариант. В `GDI` для таких случаев есть функции `CreateDIBSection` и `SetDIBits`. Я приведу 2 примера, как ими пользоваться в таких случаях. Допустим, мы хотим оперировать пикселами 32битной глубины, независимо от того, какого формата исходный файл (глубина, компрессия).

1. Загружаем растр из файла.

   ```
   std::ifstream file("VGALOGO.BMP", std::ios::binary);
   std::vector<char> src((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
   PBITMAPFILEHEADER pRes = PBITMAPFILEHEADER(&src[0]);

   PBITMAPINFO srcFmt = PBITMAPINFO(pRes + 1);
   PVOID srcBits = ((char*)pRes) + pRes->bfOffBits;

   BITMAPINFO myFmt = {0};
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(myFmt.bmiHeader);
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biWidth = srcFmt->bmiHeader.biWidth;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biHeight = -srcFmt->bmiHeader.biHeight;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

   HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
   PVOID pBmp = nullptr;
   hBmp = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &myFmt, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pBmp, 0, 0);
   SetDIBits(hdc, hBmp, 0, srcFmt->bmiHeader.biHeight, srcBits, srcFmt, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
   ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
   ```
2. Загружаем растр из ресурсов.

   ```
   HRSRC hRSrc = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SO771000), RT_RCDATA);
   HGLOBAL hRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hRSrc);
   PBITMAPFILEHEADER pRes = PBITMAPFILEHEADER(LockResource(hRes));

   PBITMAPINFO srcFmt = PBITMAPINFO(pRes + 1);
   PVOID srcBits = ((char*)pRes) + pRes->bfOffBits;

   BITMAPINFO myFmt = {0};
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(myFmt.bmiHeader);
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biWidth = srcFmt->bmiHeader.biWidth;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biHeight = -srcFmt->bmiHeader.biHeight;
   myFmt.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

   HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
   PVOID pBmp = nullptr;
   hBmp = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &myFmt, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pBmp, 0, 0);
   SetDIBits(hdc, hBmp, 0, srcFmt->bmiHeader.biHeight, srcBits, srcFmt, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
   ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
   ```

Собственно, разница только в первых 3х строчках. В обоих случаях формат растра, которым Вы будете оперировать, задается в структуре `myFmt`.

`CreateDIBSection` создает растр с таким форматом, а `SetDIBits` делает как раз ту работу, которую Вы не хотите делать сами - конвертирует данные из исходного формата в `myFmt`. `LoadImage`, к слову, делает то же самое с флагом `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION`, только не дает возможности выбрать формат.

Сами данные расположены по адресу `pBmp`. За этим блоком памяти следить не надо, он будет освобожден автоматически, при удалении `hBmp`.

Если все операции завершились успешно (я опустил проверки для упрощения), то `pBmp` указывает на массив `RGBQUAD`, независимо от формата исходного `*.bmp`.

Для примера, я вывел этот растр в окно, и дал возможность рисовать мышью прямо в памяти этого растра:

```
...
DIBSECTION bmp;
GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);
...

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    if (wParam & MK_LBUTTON) {
        int x = (short)LOWORD(lParam);
        int y = (short)HIWORD(lParam);
        if ((x >= 0) && (x < bmp.dsBm.bmWidth)) {
            if ((y >= 0) && (y < bmp.dsBm.bmHeight)) {
                auto &pixel = ((RGBQUAD*)pBmp)[y * bmp.dsBm.bmWidth + x];

                pixel.rgbRed = 255;
                pixel.rgbGreen = 0;
                pixel.rgbBlue = 0;

                InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, FALSE);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HGDIOBJ hSysBmp = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBmp);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bmp.dsBm.bmWidth, bmp.dsBm.bmHeight, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hSysBmp);
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Если не все понятно, могу приложить демонстрационный проект. Вот этот `VGALOGO.BMP`, к примеру, был `4хбитным` с компрессией `RLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще использовать GDI+, она и под С++ написана:

```
#include <GdiPlus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;

#pragma comment(lib, "GdiPlus.lib")

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput; 
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken; 
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL); // загружаем         ресурсы gdi

    //создаем окно, получаем hwnd

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    Bitmap bm(L"picture.bmp"); // грузим файл
    Graphics temp(&bm); // связали графический объект с загруженным bmp
    Color cl;
    temp.GetPixel(0,0, &cl); // получили цвет пиксела
    temp.SetPixel(1,1, cl); // установили цвет пиксела
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);


    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken); // выгружаем ресурсы gdi
    return 0;
}
```

Чисто символический пример, все в главной функции..единственное, скорость этих методов - ужасна(Set\GetPixel)